# Calculate the determinant of a matrix given a simple condition

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have been given this set of three inequations (involving three unknowns):

$\underbrace{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x-1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & y-1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & z-1 \end{array} \right)}_{\text{A}}\left( \begin{array}{c} 
a \\
b \\
c \end{array}\right) \geq \left( \begin{array}{c} 
0 \\
0 \\
0 \end{array}\right)$

Given that inequality, the problem asks me to make an assumption on the determinant of the matrix (i.e. to find an equation that links $x$, $y$, and $z$).

I could solve the problem if there was an equality symbol (instead of a greater-or-equal-than symbol): it would be as simple as saying $det(A)=0$.

I could simply say that the condition is just $det(A) \geq 0$. Is this correct? If so, how can I get to that conclusion? A subtle hint is more than acceptable in order to help me solve this simple problem.

Comment: It's really the first time that I have ever seen a group of inequalities represented in a matrix form.

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are nonnegative and $a+b+c>0$, it can be shown that $a,b,c$ are actually all positive and $\det(A)\ge0$. However, I'm not sure if anything can be said about $\det(A)$ in general.